# collect a list of Rows to a dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections, apache-spark-sql

I have a `List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` 
which I got from a `ListBuffer[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]()`

How do I turn this into a dataframe?
obviously `.toDF` (or `RDD`) does not work...

Comment: you can convert it to RDD by sc.parallelize(your List[Row]). and then you can convert it into dataframe, but not sure what will be the dataframe structure.

Comment: it's still an `RDD[Row]` and won't be converted by `toDF`.....

Comment: import sqlContext.implicits._ and then use toDF(your column names), on the RDD[T]